# Calling a function in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

This title is probably not appropriate as I have no idea what to call it.

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController 
{

    @IBAction func someFunc(sender: AnyObject)
   {
       displayAlertMessage(someString)
   }


    func displayAlertMessage(alertMessage: String)
     {
       let alert = UIAlertController(title, message, preferredStyle);
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title, style, handler);

        alert.addAction(dismissAction);
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated, completion);
     }
   }
 }
```

So the above structure will work, but with the way I'm doing things, displayAlertMessage will be redundant in other views. So I want to move it to its own class.

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController 
 {

    @IBAction func someFunc(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        AlertMessageViewController().displayAlertMessage(someString)
    } 
}


class AlertMessageViewController: UIViewController {

    func displayAlertMessage(alertMessage: String)
   {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title, message, preferredStyle);
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title, style, handler);

        alert.addAction(dismissAction);
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated, completion);
    }

}
```

But of course, I get an error saying

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

So from my understanding, I'm guessing the error occurred because AlertMessageViewController is not attached to anything? So I believe I can create another UIViewController, and then link them. But then everytime I want to display an alert message, it will switch views instead of just a small window popping up. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AlertMessageViewController {

    static func displayAlertMessage(alertMessage: String,viewController:UIViewController) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title, message, preferredStyle);
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title, style, handler);

        alert.addAction(dismissAction);
        viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated, completion);

    }

}
```

and you can call it in this way:

```
AlertMessageViewController.displayAlertMessage("message",viewController:yourControllerInstance)
```

Comment: So wait, what kind of class is AlertMessageViewController now? How come AlertViewMessageController.displayAlertMessage works without needing the brackets? As in AlertViewMessageController().displayAlertMessage. Because of it being static now?

Comment: I just try to following your approach in order to isolate the code presenting the message in a UIAlertController. I add static to the function so you don't need to create an instance of AlertMessageViewController. I would call the class AlertMessageViewControllerUtils instead of AlertMessageViewController. It is just a class extending anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what viewController to pass into AlertMessageViewController.displayAlertMessage("message",viewController:yourControllerInstance). If we stick with my example above, I would think to use "OneViewController", but I get an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'OneViewController.Type' to expteced argument type 'UIViewController'.

Comment: inside you func someFunc(sender: AnyObject) write AlertMessageViewController.displayAlertMessage("message",viewController:self)

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend `UIViewController` class

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func displayAlertMessage(alertMessage: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController("YOUR_TITLE", alertMessage, YOUR_STYLE);
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction("YOUR_TITLE", YIUR_STYLE, YOUR_HANDLER);

        alert.addAction(dismissAction);
        self.presentViewController(alert, true, YOUR_COMPLETION:BLOCK);
    }
}
```

And then you can call `myController.displayAlertMessage("This is my alert")`

Obviously, the extension cannot contain stored properties, so you have to pass the all the parameters you need